# Calcular distancias entre duas coordenadas

Tags: php, matemática, coordenadas

Estou usando essa função abaixo para calcular a diferença entre duas coordenadas. Atraves do google maps é informado uma diferença de uns 2 a 3km. Mas a função está me retornando o resultado 56.480188542761 Km.
Gostaria de saber se tem algo errado na função ou se existe mais algum calculo a ser feito.

```
function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

    $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "K") {
        return ($miles * 1.609344);
    } else if ($unit == "N") {
        return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
    }
}

// -12.971683, -38.460108 = bairro pernambues em salvador
// -12.981290, -38.465043 = shopping iguatemi em salvador
echo distancia(-12.971683, -38.460108, -12.981290, -38.981290, "k") . " Km<br />";
```

Comment: Só pra mim entender melhor, K = kilometro, e o N?

Comment: O N é para milhas náuticas (dado o factor de conversão usado).

Comment: Quem sabe!?  :)  Esquece o N. Precisarei apenas de quilometros.

Comment: Outra coisa @RafaelSoufraz, a distância que o google maps informa, considera as ruas a trafegar, e quando você utiliza a fórmula de Haversine, ela calcula a distância em linha reta.

Comment: Eu sei disso. Mas ainda assim não justifica o resultado da função. 56.480188542761 Km

Comment: Tenta com a resposta que coloquei.

Comment: 2 respostas com valores diferentes de resultado, cuidado para não fazer asneira.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fórmula de Haversine aplicada em PHP

```
function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

$lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
$lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
$lon1 = deg2rad($lon1);
$lon2 = deg2rad($lon2);

$dist = (6371 * acos( cos( $lat1 ) * cos( $lat2 ) * cos( $lon2 - $lon1 ) + sin( $lat1 ) * sin($lat2) ) );
$dist = number_format($dist, 2, '.', '');
return $dist;
}

echo distancia(-12.9813346,-38.4653612, -12.9741491,-38.4696483) . " Km<br />";

// 0.92 Km
```

Ou assim, verificando o Delta.

```
function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {

$lat1 = deg2rad($lat1);
$lat2 = deg2rad($lat2);
$lon1 = deg2rad($lon1);
$lon2 = deg2rad($lon2);

$latD = $lat2 - $lat1;
$lonD = $lon2 - $lon1;

$dist = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latD / 2), 2) +
cos($lat1) * cos($lat2) * pow(sin($lonD / 2), 2)));
$dist = $dist * 6371;
return number_format($dist, 2, '.', '');
}

echo distancia(-12.9813346,-38.4653612, -12.9741491,-38.4696483) . " Km<br />";

// 0.92 Km
```

Comment: Eu utilizei esta mesma fórmula, para encontrar os pontos mais próximos em linha reta, dentro de um cadastro de cidades, e após isto, traçar a distãncia das rotas das cidades mais próximas, já com coordenadas estabelecidas com a API do googleMaps.
Dá uma olhada: https://gist.github.com/aymone/00c4e4e8be907bdedda7

Answer (score 2):

Seguindo Haversine do [wikipedia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%B3rmula_de_Haversine)

```
<?php

function distancia($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2) {
$lat = deg2rad($lat2-$lat1);
$lon = deg2rad($lon2-$lon1);
$t = sin($lat/2) * sin($lat/2) + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) *sin(lon/2) * sin(lon/2);
$l = 2 * atan2(sqrt($t), sqrt(1-$t));
$result = 6371 * $l;
return $result;
}



echo distancia(-12.9813346,-38.4653612, -12.9741491,-38.4696483) . " Km";


?>
```

Resultado aqui foi `0.798991145405 Km`

Comment: Porque retirou o seu resultado?

Comment: Então, a fórmula original é em graus, então não faz sentido calcular o delta em radianos, pelo menos entendo desta forma, posso estar errado.

Answer (score 0):

Para se calcular a distancia entre dois pontos,use a seguinte formula:

Raiz quadrada de: `( Xa - Xb )^2 + ( Ya - Yb )^2`

Exemplo

`12, 14` é a coordenada A.

`4, 3` é a coordenada B.

O primeiro valor da coordenada equivale a X e o segundo a Y,portanto:

```
`(Xa-Xb)^2+(Ya-Yb)^2` = `(12-4)^2+(14-3)^2`

= `(8)^2+(11)^2`

= `(8)^2+(11)^2`

= `64+121`
```

A distancia entre A e B é a raiz quadrada de 185 ou ~13,6

Leia http://www.brasilescola.com/matematica/distancia-entre-dois-pontos.htm

Comment: Obrigado. Me explicou como calcular mas o calculo já está sendo feito. Só preciso entender o resultado final e ou converte-lo.

Comment: Isso num plano, mas a Terra é esférica (ou quase esférica).

Comment: É,eu não havia notado,só me toquei com o comentário do Marcelo sobre a Fórmula de Haversine.